# How to get tidy fill function to use groups when filling data rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, fill

I have data rows with a common date and record number, but there are different columns with data in each record, such as in this data:

```
my_data <- structure(list(Station_Number = c("0045", "0045", "0045", "0045"), 
Station_Name = c("Scottsbluff 2NW", "Scottsbluff 2NW", "Scottsbluff 2NW", "Scottsbluff 
2NW"), NWSLI = c("SBMN1", "SBMN1", "SBMN1", "SBMN1"), Station_Legacy_Name = 
c("Scottsbluff", "Scottsbluff", "Scottsbluff", "Scottsbluff"), Lat = c(41.89175, 
41.89175, 41.89175, 41.89175), Lon = c(-103.6814722, -103.6814722, -103.6814722, 
-103.6814722), Elev_m = c("1198.54", "1198.54", "1198.54", "1198.54"), TIMESTAMP = 
c("2017-06-18 04:00:00","2017-06-18 04:00:00", "2017-06-18 04:01:00", "2017-06-18 04:01:00"), RECORD = c(214037L, 214037L, 214038L, 214038L), Ta_2m_Avg = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), TaMax_2m = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
LithBatt_Min = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), MaintMode = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), WndSpd5s_3m_Avg = c(1.373, NA, 1.786, NA), 
WndMaxSpd5s_3m_Avg = c(NA, 1.373, NA, 1.786), source = 
c("E:\\Data_Collected_withDups/Scottsbluff/NE-Scottsbluff-CR1000-Table018-dat", 
"E:\\Data_Collected_withDups/Scottsbluff/NE-Scottsbluff-CR1000-Table018-dat.1.backup", 
"E:\\Data_Collected_withDups/Scottsbluff/NE-Scottsbluff-CR1000-Table018-dat", 
"E:\\Data_Collected_withDups/Scottsbluff/NE-Scottsbluff-CR1000-Table018-dat.1.backup"
)), row.names = c(2989579L, 5089877L, 2989580L, 5089878L), class = "data.frame")
```

Ignoring the last column, I want to group by TIMESTAMP and fill everything.  I've tried various versions of

```
my_data[,1:15] |> group_by(TIMESTAMP) |> tidyr::fill(everything(), .direction = 'up') |> 
head()
```

Shouldn't this produce a data frame with two rows, with "WndSpd5s_3m_Avg" and "WndMaxSpd5s_3m_Avg" variables filled in?  I've tried many versions of this with no luck.  I don't know how/if to use the head() part of code in this case.  Any help would be great.

Comment: I’d try “slice(n=1)” in place of head to get the first row per group.

Comment: @JonSpring the missing values alternate, see my answer :-)

Comment: re: using `head()` OP, you don't need it, but it is helpful if you are using dput()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to obtain the (single) non-missing entries of the WndSpd columns per timestamp, you can simply do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_data %>% 
  group_by(TIMESTAMP) %>%  
  summarize(across(c('WndSpd5s_3m_Avg', 'WndMaxSpd5s_3m_Avg'), na.omit))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   TIMESTAMP           WndSpd5s_3m_Avg WndMaxSpd5s_3m_Avg
#>   <chr>                         <dbl>              <dbl>
#> 1 2017-06-18 04:00:00            1.37               1.37
#> 2 2017-06-18 04:01:00            1.79               1.79
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Using fill does not change the number of rows of your data set (just like mutate), summarize instead will end up with one row per group (here number of unique timestamps)

Comment: side note: if you wanted to keep the other columns, you could use `summarise(my_data, across(-starts_with("Wnd"), first), across(starts_with("Wnd"), na.omit), .by = "TIMESTAMP")`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking to do?

```
library(dplyr)

my_data |>
  group_by(TIMESTAMP) |>
  mutate(WndSpd5s_3m_Avg = max(WndSpd5s_3m_Avg, na.rm = TRUE),
         WndMaxSpd5s_3m_Avg = max(WndMaxSpd5s_3m_Avg, na.rm = TRUE)) |>
  slice_head(n = 1) |>
  select(TIMESTAMP, WndSpd5s_3m_Avg, WndMaxSpd5s_3m_Avg)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   TIMESTAMP [2]
  TIMESTAMP           WndSpd5s_3m_Avg WndMaxSpd5s_3m_Avg
  <chr>                         <dbl>              <dbl>
1 2017-06-18 04:00:00            1.37               1.37
2 2017-06-18 04:01:00            1.79               1.79
```

I used `select()` to just select those 3 columns, if you removed that line it would return all the columns. Also remember to assign it to a variable if you want to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great if you're looking for just looking for a way of getting a dataframe with two rows- I'd like to address your questions though, and try to explain why your code doesn't work the way you want it to.

The function `fill()` fills in missing NA values from the row above or the row below, depending on how you set it up. It doesn't remove (or add) rows.

This is what the data looks like initially:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 15
  Station_Number Station_Name        NWSLI Station_Legacy_Name   Lat   Lon
  <chr>          <chr>               <chr> <chr>               <dbl> <dbl>
1 0045           "Scottsbluff 2NW"   SBMN1 Scottsbluff          41.9 -104.
2 0045           "Scottsbluff 2NW"   SBMN1 Scottsbluff          41.9 -104.
3 0045           "Scottsbluff 2NW"   SBMN1 Scottsbluff          41.9 -104.
4 0045           "Scottsbluff \n2NW" SBMN1 Scottsbluff          41.9 -104.
  Elev_m  TIMESTAMP           RECORD Ta_2m_Avg TaMax_2m LithBatt_Min MaintMode
  <chr>   <chr>                <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>     <int>
1 1198.54 2017-06-18 04:00:00 214037        NA       NA           NA        NA
2 1198.54 2017-06-18 04:00:00 214037        NA       NA           NA        NA
3 1198.54 2017-06-18 04:01:00 214038        NA       NA           NA        NA
4 1198.54 2017-06-18 04:01:00 214038        NA       NA           NA        NA
  WndSpd5s_3m_Avg WndMaxSpd5s_3m_Avg
            <dbl>              <dbl>
1            1.37              NA   
2           NA                  1.37
3            1.79              NA   
4           NA                  1.79
```

There's two timestamps, each with two rows. The missing values in the windspeed columns form a kind of checkerbox pattern.

When your code is run (with `direction = 'up'`), this is what the wind speed columns change to:

```
  WndSpd5s_3m_Avg WndMaxSpd5s_3m_Avg
            <dbl>              <dbl>
1            1.37               1.37
2           NA                  1.37
3            1.79               1.79
4           NA                  1.79
```

As you can see, the WndMaxSpd5s_3m_Avg values have been filled in, but not the WndSpd5s_3m_Avg values. If you were to switch `'up' to 'down', the opposite would be true.

The solution is to change the direction to either 'downup (i.e. first down and then up) or 'updown' (first up and then down) (which one might matter if you have multiple non-NA values per Timestamp, but seeing as you don't it's not important).