# How to use fill function from tidyr R package with groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, fill, coalesce

This question is a follow up to my other question, [How to get tidy fill function to use groups when filling data rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471017/how-to-get-tidy-fill-function-to-use-groups-when-filling-data-rows?noredirect=1#comment136603288_77471017).

I want to get one row per TIMESTAMP value.  I want to fill in real data, by column, whether it's character, float, or whatever.  If both TIMESTAMP rows have NA's, then I need NA returned.  I want all columns returned.

A tiny portion of my data:

```
dupped_records <- structure(list(Station_Number = c("3999", "3999", "3999", "3999"
    ), Station_Name = c("Eagle 3NW Beta", "Eagle 3NW Beta", "Eagle 3NW Beta","Eagle 3NW 
    Beta"), NWSLI = c("EEMN1", "EEMN1", "EEMN1", "EEMN1"), Station_Legacy_Name = c("Rogers 
    Farm Tower", "Rogers Farm Tower", "Rogers Farm Tower", "Rogers Farm Tower"), Lat = 
    c(40.846994, 40.846994, 40.846994, 40.846994), Lon = c(-96.467199, -96.467199, 
    -96.467199, -96.467199), Elev_m = c("368.7", "368.7", "368.7", "368.7"), TIMESTAMP = 
    c("2021-07-28 20:05:00", "2021-07-28 20:05:00", "2021-07-28 20:06:00", "2021-07-28 
    20:06:00"), RECORD = c(18L, 18L, 19L, 19L), Ta_2m_Avg = c(34.3, NA, 34.26, NA), TaMax_2m = c(34.39, 
NA, 34.35, NA), TaMaxTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:15", NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:05", 
NA), TaMin_2m = c(34.25, NA, 34.16, NA), TaMinTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:45", 
NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:50", NA), RH_2m_Avg = c(57.35, NA, 56.97, 
NA), RHMax_2m = c(58.68, NA, 57.99, NA), RHMaxTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:30", 
NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:40", NA), RHMin_2m = c(55.86, NA, 55.41, 
NA), RHMinTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:45", NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:20", 
NA), Dp_2m_Avg = c(24.68, NA, 24.53, NA), DpMax_2m = c(25.06, 
NA, 24.77, NA), DpMaxTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:25", NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:40", 
NA), DpMin_2m = c(24.19, NA, 24.06, NA), DpMinTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:45", 
NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:20", NA), HeatIndex_2m_Avg = c(41.9, NA, 
41.64, NA), HeatIndexMax_2m = c(42.51, NA, 41.95, NA), HeatIndexMaxTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:25", 
NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:45", NA), WindChill_2m_Avg = c(37.65, NA, 
37.77, NA), WindChillMin_2m = c(37.47, NA, 37.56, NA), WindChillMinTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:45", 
NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:20", NA), WndAveSpd_3m = c(2.746, NA, 3.796, 
NA), WndVecMagAve_3m = c(2.594, NA, 3.607, NA), WndAveDir_3m = c(166.5, 
NA, 152.6, NA), WndAveDirSD_3m = c(19.03, NA, 18.05, NA), WndMaxSpd5s_3m = c(5.165, 
NA, 5.498, NA), WndMaxSpd5sTime_3m = c("2021-07-28 20:05:00", 
NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:05", NA), WndMax_5sec_Dir_3m = c(158.3, 
NA, 162.8, NA), PresAvg_1pnt5m = c(972.3953, NA, 972.3508, NA
), PresMax_1pnt5m = c(972.4536, NA, 972.42, NA), PresMaxTime_1pnt5m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:25", 
NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:10", NA), PresMin_1pnt5m = c(972.3868, 
NA, 972.2872, NA), PresMinTime_1pnt5m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:35", 
NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:50", NA), Solar_2m_Avg = c(771.1, NA, 776.1, 
NA), Rain_1m_Tot = c(0, NA, 0, NA), Ts_bare_10cm_Avg = c(32.98, 
NA, 33.01, NA), TsMax_bare_10cm = c(33, NA, 33.02, NA), TsMaxTime_bare_10cm = c("2021-07-28 20:05:00", 
NA, "2021-07-28 20:06:00", NA), TsMin_bare_10cm = c(32.97, NA, 
33, NA), TsMinTime_bare_10cm = c("2021-07-28 20:04:10", NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:05", 
NA), BattVolts_Min = c(12.77, NA, 12.77, NA), LithBatt_Min = c(3.56, 
NA, 3.56, NA), MaintMode = c(0L, NA, 0L, NA), WS_ms_S_WVT = c(NA, 
3.082, NA, 3.614), SlrW_Avg = c(NA, 854, NA, 859), SlrW_Max = c(NA, 
858, NA, 862), SlrW_TMx = c(NA, "2021-07-28 20:04:05", NA, "2021-07-28 20:06:00"
), SlrW = c(NA, 856, NA, 862), SlrW_Std = c(NA, 2.334, NA, 2.376
), WS_Dir = c(NA, 164L, NA, 128L), WS_ms_Avg = c(NA, 3.082, NA, 
3.614), WS_ms_Max = c(NA, 5.17, NA, 5.71), WS_ms_TMx = c(NA, 
"2021-07-28 20:05:00", NA, "2021-07-28 20:05:05"), WS_Diag = c(NA, 
0L, NA, 0L), SmplsF = c(NA, 1L, NA, 1L), Diag1F = c(NA, 0L, NA, 
0L), Diag2F = c(NA, 0L, NA, 0L), Diag4F = c(NA, 0L, NA, 0L), 
    Diag8F = c(NA, 0L, NA, 0L), Diag9F = c(NA, 0L, NA, 0L), Diag10F = c(NA, 
    0L, NA, 0L), NNDF = c(NA, 0L, NA, 0L), WindDir_D1_WVT = c(NA, 
    170.6, NA, 150.3), WindDir_SD1_WVT = c(NA, 16.43, NA, 14.95
    ), source = c("E:\\Data_Collected_withDups/3999/3999_1min.csv-20230216_0122", 
    "E:\\Data_Collected_withDups/3999/3999_1min_exp.csv-20230216_0122", 
    "E:\\Data_Collected_withDups/3999/3999_1min.csv-20230216_0122", 
    "E:\\Data_Collected_withDups/3999/3999_1min_exp.csv-20230216_0122"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1886274:1886277)
```

The result I want is:

```
no_dupped_records <- structure(list(Station_Number = c(3999L, 3999L), Station_Name = c("Eagle 3NW Beta", 
"Eagle 3NW Beta"), NWSLI = c("EEMN1", "EEMN1"), Station_Legacy_Name = c("Rogers Farm Tower", 
"Rogers Farm Tower"), Lat = c(40.846994, 40.846994), Lon = c(-96.467199, 
-96.467199), Elev_m = c(368.7, 368.7), TIMESTAMP = c("2021-07-28 20:05:00", 
"2021-07-28 20:06:00"), RECORD = 18:19, Ta_2m_Avg = c(34.3, 34.26
), TaMax_2m = c(34.39, 34.35), TaMaxTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:15", 
"2021-07-28 20:05:05"), TaMin_2m = c(34.25, 34.16), TaMinTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:45", 
"2021-07-28 20:05:50"), RH_2m_Avg = c(57.35, 56.97), RHMax_2m = c(58.68, 
57.99), RHMaxTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:30", "2021-07-28 20:05:40"
), RHMin_2m = c(55.86, 55.41), RHMinTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:45", 
"2021-07-28 20:05:20"), Dp_2m_Avg = c(24.68, 24.53), DpMax_2m = c(25.06, 
24.77), DpMaxTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:25", "2021-07-28 20:05:40"
), DpMin_2m = c(24.19, 24.06), DpMinTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:45", 
"2021-07-28 20:05:20"), HeatIndex_2m_Avg = c(41.9, 41.64), HeatIndexMax_2m = c(42.51, 
41.95), HeatIndexMaxTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:25", "2021-07-28 20:05:45"
), WindChill_2m_Avg = c(37.65, 37.77), WindChillMin_2m = c(37.47, 
37.56), WindChillMinTime_2m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:45", "2021-07-28 20:05:20"
), WndAveSpd_3m = c(2.746, 3.796), WndVecMagAve_3m = c(2.594, 
3.607), WndAveDir_3m = c(166.5, 152.6), WndAveDirSD_3m = c(19.03, 
18.05), WndMaxSpd5s_3m = c(5.165, 5.498), WndMaxSpd5sTime_3m = c("2021-07-28 20:05:00", 
"2021-07-28 20:05:05"), WndMax_5sec_Dir_3m = c(158.3, 162.8), 
    PresAvg_1pnt5m = c(972.3953, 972.3508), PresMax_1pnt5m = c(972.4536, 
    972.42), PresMaxTime_1pnt5m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:25", "2021-07-28 20:05:10"
    ), PresMin_1pnt5m = c(972.3868, 972.2872), PresMinTime_1pnt5m = c("2021-07-28 20:04:35", 
    "2021-07-28 20:05:50"), Solar_2m_Avg = c(771.1, 776.1), Rain_1m_Tot = c(0L, 
    0L), Ts_bare_10cm_Avg = c(32.98, 33.01), TsMax_bare_10cm = c(33, 
    33.02), TsMaxTime_bare_10cm = c("2021-07-28 20:05:00", "2021-07-28 20:06:00"
    ), TsMin_bare_10cm = c(32.97, 33), TsMinTime_bare_10cm = c("2021-07-28 20:04:10", 
    "2021-07-28 20:05:05"), BattVolts_Min = c(12.77, 12.77), 
    LithBatt_Min = c(3.56, 3.56), MaintMode = c(0L, 0L), WS_ms_S_WVT = c(3.082, 
    3.614), SlrW_Avg = c(854L, 859L), SlrW_Max = c(858L, 862L
    ), SlrW_TMx = c("2021-07-28 20:04:05", "2021-07-28 20:06:00"
    ), SlrW = c(856L, 862L), SlrW_Std = c(2.334, 2.376), WS_Dir = c(164L, 
    128L), WS_ms_Avg = c(3.082, 3.614), WS_ms_Max = c(5.17, 5.71
    ), WS_ms_TMx = c("2021-07-28 20:05:00", "2021-07-28 20:05:05"
    ), WS_Diag = c(0L, 0L), SmplsF = c(1L, 1L), Diag1F = c(0L, 
    0L), Diag2F = c(0L, 0L), Diag4F = c(0L, 0L), Diag8F = c(0L, 
    0L), Diag9F = c(0L, 0L), Diag10F = c(0L, 0L), NNDF = c(0L, 
    0L), WindDir_D1_WVT = c(170.6, 150.3), WindDir_SD1_WVT = c(16.43, 
    14.95), source = c("E:\\Data_Collected_withDups/3999/3999_1min.csv-20230216_0122", 
    "E:\\Data_Collected_withDups/3999/3999_1min.csv-20230216_0122"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

It looks like I need to use mutate somehow to get what I want, based on the answers to  my previous question.  But how?  I need all columns returned.

Here are two statements I thought might work.  I get the error that everything must be used within a selecting function.

```
dupped_records |> group_by(TIMESTAMP) |> mutate_all(fill(everything(), .direction = 'up'))
```

This statement does nothing.  Why?

```
dupped_records |> group_by(TIMESTAMP) |> mutate(across(fill(everything(), .direction = 'up')))
```

Anyway, I appreciate your help, as always.  A quick EDIT: Is there a way to do this with dplyr::coalesce?

Comment: also, why do you keep on saying how can I use fill for this, when fill is clearly not the one for the job? fill() keeps the same number of rows, but replaces NAs with the above or below value.

Comment: also, it's good practice to keep your datetimes in datetime format, so you don't (as in this case), have `unique(dupped_records$TIMESTAMP)` be `[1] "2021-07-28 20:05:00"       "2021-07-28 20:06:00"      
[3] "2021-07-28 \n    20:06:00"`, when #2 and #3 are the same event

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer.  I can't get it to work for my data.  Like I said, I need all columns returned.  If I could get it to work, I wouldn't be asking again.

Comment: if it wasn't working, then post a comment, don't just ask the same question over again

Comment: Mark addresses it by converting the TIMESTAMP column to a datetime, but note that your example data row 3+4 do not match due to a line break in the row 4 version: `$ TIMESTAMP  <chr> "2021-07-28 20:05:00", "2021-07-28 20:05:00", "2021-07-28 20:06:00", "2021-07-28 \n    20:06:00"`

Comment: I don't think `coalesce()` is the thing you're looking for. It finds the first non-NA value within each row (of a subset of the dataframe), whereas you want to find the first non-NA value within each column

Comment: what would you like to happen with the source column?

Comment: I would like it to be from the first row of each timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

dupped_records |>
  mutate(TIMESTAMP = ymd_hms(TIMESTAMP)) |>
  summarise(across(Station_Number:RECORD, first), across(Ta_2m_Avg:WindDir_SD1_WVT, na.omit), .by = "TIMESTAMP")
```

```
            TIMESTAMP Station_Number   Station_Name NWSLI
1 2021-07-28 20:05:00           3999 Eagle 3NW Beta EEMN1
2 2021-07-28 20:06:00           3999 Eagle 3NW Beta EEMN1
      Station_Legacy_Name      Lat      Lon Elev_m RECORD Ta_2m_Avg TaMax_2m
1 Rogers \n    Farm Tower 40.84699 -96.4672  368.7     18     34.30    34.39
2       Rogers Farm Tower 40.84699 -96.4672  368.7     19     34.26    34.35
         TaMaxTime_2m TaMin_2m        TaMinTime_2m RH_2m_Avg RHMax_2m
1 2021-07-28 20:04:15    34.25 2021-07-28 20:04:45     57.35    58.68
2 2021-07-28 20:05:05    34.16 2021-07-28 20:05:50     56.97    57.99
         RHMaxTime_2m RHMin_2m        RHMinTime_2m Dp_2m_Avg DpMax_2m
1 2021-07-28 20:04:30    55.86 2021-07-28 20:04:45     24.68    25.06
2 2021-07-28 20:05:40    55.41 2021-07-28 20:05:20     24.53    24.77
         DpMaxTime_2m DpMin_2m        DpMinTime_2m HeatIndex_2m_Avg
1 2021-07-28 20:04:25    24.19 2021-07-28 20:04:45            41.90
2 2021-07-28 20:05:40    24.06 2021-07-28 20:05:20            41.64
  HeatIndexMax_2m HeatIndexMaxTime_2m WindChill_2m_Avg WindChillMin_2m
1           42.51 2021-07-28 20:04:25            37.65           37.47
2           41.95 2021-07-28 20:05:45            37.77           37.56
  WindChillMinTime_2m WndAveSpd_3m WndVecMagAve_3m WndAveDir_3m WndAveDirSD_3m
1 2021-07-28 20:04:45        2.746           2.594        166.5          19.03
2 2021-07-28 20:05:20        3.796           3.607        152.6          18.05
  WndMaxSpd5s_3m  WndMaxSpd5sTime_3m WndMax_5sec_Dir_3m PresAvg_1pnt5m
1          5.165 2021-07-28 20:05:00              158.3       972.3953
2          5.498 2021-07-28 20:05:05              162.8       972.3508
  PresMax_1pnt5m  PresMaxTime_1pnt5m PresMin_1pnt5m  PresMinTime_1pnt5m
1       972.4536 2021-07-28 20:04:25       972.3868 2021-07-28 20:04:35
2       972.4200 2021-07-28 20:05:10       972.2872 2021-07-28 20:05:50
  Solar_2m_Avg Rain_1m_Tot Ts_bare_10cm_Avg TsMax_bare_10cm TsMaxTime_bare_10cm
1        771.1           0            32.98           33.00 2021-07-28 20:05:00
2        776.1           0            33.01           33.02 2021-07-28 20:06:00
  TsMin_bare_10cm TsMinTime_bare_10cm BattVolts_Min LithBatt_Min MaintMode
1           32.97 2021-07-28 20:04:10         12.77         3.56         0
2           33.00 2021-07-28 20:05:05         12.77         3.56         0
  WS_ms_S_WVT SlrW_Avg SlrW_Max            SlrW_TMx SlrW SlrW_Std WS_Dir
1       3.082      854      858 2021-07-28 20:04:05  856    2.334    164
2       3.614      859      862 2021-07-28 20:06:00  862    2.376    128
  WS_ms_Avg WS_ms_Max           WS_ms_TMx WS_Diag SmplsF Diag1F Diag2F Diag4F
1     3.082      5.17 2021-07-28 20:05:00       0      1      0      0      0
2     3.614      5.71 2021-07-28 20:05:05       0      1      0      0      0
  Diag8F Diag9F Diag10F NNDF WindDir_D1_WVT WindDir_SD1_WVT
1      0      0       0    0          170.6           16.43
2      0      0       0    0          150.3           14.95
```